# Serviço do Windows utilizando método async, há necessidade?

Tags: c#, .net, async, assincronismo, services

Em meu sistema, tenho algumas rotinas auxiliares, que são disparadas em horários definidos, fora do expediente de trabalho.

Essas rotinas são executadas por um programa de serviço do Windows.

Teria necessidade de rodar esses serviços assíncronos? Ou seja, utilizando métodos `async`?

Pelo que sei o principal motivo da utilização de métodos `async` é para não bloquear a tela do usuário enquanto rodamos alguma tarefa.

Agora, para serviço não vejo tanto motivo para utilizar tais métodos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem muitos detalhes, mas eu diria que não. Em geral a assincronicidade é para melhorar a experiência do usuário, que no caso não existe. Claro que poderia ter a necessidade se este serviço respondesse à vários usuários simultâneos, mas não parece ser o caso.